# Unexpected empty space using MaterialUI Grid

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm using the material UI react components, particularly the problem seems to be about the [Grid component](https://material-ui.com/api/grid/). I'm getting a very weird space as shown in the image and I cannot find out where it is coming from.

I've reduced the problem to the minimum possible and now it's just a Grid inside a Grid that contains two images.

```
<Grid container direction={"column"} style={{ "background-color": "red" }}>
  <Grid item>
    <Grid container style={{ "background-color": "blue" }}>
      <Grid item xs={11} style={{ "background-color": "purple" }}>
        <CustomImg />
        <CustomImg />
      </Grid>
    </Grid>
  </Grid>
</Grid>
```

[image: space in Grid]
**I don't understand where the *red* space is coming from.**

**A clue**: If I change the `<Grid item xs={11}` to be `xs={12}` or remove the whole `xs={...}` then the space goes away....

Here is the codesanbox so you can hopefully tell me what I am doing wrong:
https://codesandbox.io/s/x7q8q0rr5z

Comment: Isn't the Grid 12 columns in width, and when you set `xs` to be `11`, you set it to be 91.6% in width for extra small screens and larger?

Comment: That's right `11` is the purple area and `1` the blue, that's expected. It's the red one the one that I don't understand

Comment: I've reduced the problem to only use Flexbox, it's described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51445959/unexpected-empty-space-using-flexbox

Answer (score 0):

After playing in your sandbox, I believe it's caused by you having the two CustomImg components in the inner Grid item. If you have one, it goes away. Hopefully this helps.