# Unexpected empty space using Flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I've reduced the problem to the minimum possible where the issue is still present.

[image]

**I don't understand where the orange space is coming from.**

**A clue**: Removing one image the orange space goes away.

```css
.OutterContainer {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;

  flex-direction: column;

  background-color: orange;
}

.InnerContainer {
  display: flex;

  background-color: blue;
}

.InnerItem {
  flex-basis: 90%;

  background-color: purple;
}
```

```html
<div class="OutterContainer">
  <div>
    <div class="InnerContainer">
      <div class="InnerItem">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you mean orange?

Comment: Removing the div between the outer container and the inner container also causes it to go away.

Comment: Remove `flex-wrap: wrap;`

Comment: @j08691 we can also remove the flex-basis and many other things ... but why that space with those CSS?

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas I need to keep this structure. I know it's a bit weird but that's what is left after removing all parts in my UI that are not necessary to show this problem.

Comment: @j08691 I could, but I want to understand why it is wrapping if there is actually nothing to wrap

Comment: Try .OutterContainer > div {

Comment: am sure it's a bug ... let's wait for Michael_B to confirm this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's somehow a bug but here is my explanation of the behavior:

Let's remove some properties and follow the code.

```css
.OutterContainer {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  /*flex-direction: column;*/
  background-color: orange;
}

.InnerContainer {
  display: flex;
  background-color: blue;
}

.InnerItem {
  /*flex-basis: 90%;*/
  background-color: purple;
}
```

```html
<div class="OutterContainer">
  <div style="border:1px solid;">
    <div class="InnerContainer">
      <div class="InnerItem">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This code seems ok. We have a flex container with a row direction and a `div` as a flex item. This `div` will by default fit its content width. Same thing for the `innerItem`. Now by adding a flex-basis lower than 100% both images won't fit the container width and we will have a line break thus the height of all the elements will increase (including the orange box).

```css
.OutterContainer {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  /*flex-direction: column;*/
  background-color: orange;
}

.InnerContainer {
  display: flex;
  background-color: blue;
}

.InnerItem {
  flex-basis: 90%;
  background-color: purple;
}
```

```html
<div class="OutterContainer">
  <div style="border:1px solid;">
    <div class="InnerContainer">
      <div class="InnerItem">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Now if we switch to a column direction the same height is kept. It's like the browser did the calculation of the height based on the row direction and kept the result for the column direction.

```css
.OutterContainer {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: orange;
}

.InnerContainer {
  display: flex;
  background-color: blue;
}

.InnerItem {
  flex-basis: 90%;
  background-color: purple;
}
```

```html
<div class="OutterContainer">
  <div style="border:1px solid;">
    <div class="InnerContainer">
      <div class="InnerItem">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

There is also the fact that the default alignment is strech so if you change the alignment to something else we will get back to the previous state:

```css
.OutterContainer {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items:flex-start;
  background-color: orange;
}

.InnerContainer {
  display: flex;
  background-color: blue;
}

.InnerItem {
  flex-basis: 90%;
  background-color: purple;
}
```

```html
<div class="OutterContainer">
  <div style="border:1px solid;">
    <div class="InnerContainer">
      <div class="InnerItem">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

With one image you cannot have the issue because logically there is no way to have a line break like with more than one.

Comment: This seems like as good an explanation as any. I'll add two observations: First, the orange box represents the height of the primary flex container (`.OutterContainer`) in `row` direction. The setting in the code is `column`. So it looks like the browser is first calculating the container's height in the default `row` direction, then shifting to the author-defined `column` direction, but not going back to adjust the container's height. (I see you've mentioned this in your answer already.)

Comment: Second, note the `flex-basis: 90%` on `.InnerItem`. If it is removed, or if `flex-grow: 1` is added, the problem appears to be resolved ([demo](https://jsfiddle.net/eaqh619d/7/)).

Comment: In any case, there seem to be multiple bugs in play here. *Avoiding so many nested containers is one solution.* Also, I only tested in Chrome. Results may vary in other browsers.

Comment: @Michael_B For your second note, yes the flex-basis is the culprit as it's chaging the height by creating the line break. By the way, I think the issue is related to alignment ... all the values of alignment will give a good result but not the stretch one (the default one). So the height is somehow correct for the column direction ... I don't know how to explain it well, but there is a kind of cycle, the height of the inner element is calculated then the outer one is calculated then the stretch value change the behavior of the inner one and this one is recalculated again BUT the outer one no.

Comment: I get what you're saying. Explanation is fine. Looking at the big picture, however, we can generally expect problems when nesting multiple containers. Especially when they don't even seem necessary (like that div child of the primary container). And then throw in images. Yeah, you're begging for a broken layout, and at least one of the major browsers will deliver.

Comment: Isn't it fine to nest flex containers? The question has a very simplified layout, the original one has more elements but I removed them for the sake of simplicity. See here [the original problem](http://i.imgur.com/TF7WCcj.png). The images are the two trumpets and quite far away the orange extra space. Is that a wrong use of flex containers?

Comment: @dnaranjo if Michael_B said it's not fine then it's not fine :p

Comment: I'm not saying it's bad to nest flex containers. I'm saying that I've observed, over a few years of reviewing flex and grid problems, that nesting *too many* containers can cause problems in some browsers. It's like there's an arbitrary limit at which point something breaks. My suggestion was simply to minimize the number of nested containers. (@Temani, too much credit, but thanks).

Comment: Thanks @Michael_B for the clarification

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming these pictures are supposed to wrap while they are in the `.InnerItem`. After playing around with your fiddle for a bit, it seems the `.OutterContainer` was expanding (and showing that orange space) because of its `display: flex`. I think this is redudant as you already specfiy `display: flex` inside of your `.InnerContainer`. I removed this CSS rule and was able to achieve the same picture wrapping by pasting multiple pictures inside of the `.InnerItem`.

```css
.OutterContainer {
  flex-wrap: wrap;

  flex-direction: column;

  background-color: orange;
}

.InnerContainer {
  display: flex;

  background-color: blue;
}

.InnerItem {
  flex-basis: 90%;

  background-color: purple;
}
```

```html
<div class="OutterContainer">
    <div>
        <div class="InnerContainer">
            <div class="InnerItem">
                <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100">
                <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: your removed display:flex so you should also remove the other flex properties

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem in React Material-UI library. I got huge empty space below the `TableContainer` in this code:

```
<Grid item>                    
    <TableContainer>
        <Table>
            <TableHead>
                <TableRow>
                    //some cells
                </TableRow>
            </TableHead>
            <TableBody>
                    //some rows
            </TableBody>
        </Table>
    </TableContainer>

   //here I got huge empty unexpected space

</Grid>
```

Then I add `container` keyword in `Grid` and empty space disappeared.

```
<Grid item container>                    
    <TableContainer>
        <Table>
            //the same code
        </Table>
    </TableContainer>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

In case anybody runs in similar issue here is workaround that worked for me. For parent element set line-height to 0. Then set min-height for all children so they don't shrink too much. You still have lot of empty lines on bottom of parent element... but they don't take any space.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, and I found that setting

```
.OutterContainer > div {
 width: 100%;
}
```

solved the issue, even though in practice the width of the div does not change with this setting, it hinders the browser to render the empty space (orange) below.

I could not fully understand the cause of the problem, but I noticed that the empty (orange) space appears to take the same height as the last flex child element inside the flex container (.InnerContainer). Indeed if you manually set the height of the second image to 25px f.ex., the empty space will have a height of 25px as well, independently from the height of the first image.

It seems as if the browser wanted to wrap the last flex child to a new line and creates the space for it, but the wrap is not happening of course because there is enough space in the first line.